# How to load and import a CSS/JS file from the phone in phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I use a javascript code to download a CSS file to the phone.

The code works well and it saves the CSS file in this path:

```
file:///data/user/0/com.my.app/files/file.css
```

Now I want to locally load it with a html code (in my server) like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///data/user/0/com.my.app/files/file.css">
```

but it doesn't work.

I also tried to put the CSS file directly into the package (.apk and .ipa) in a css folder in the www folder, but this code doesn't work too:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/www/css/file.css">
```

Is there a way to load a CSS/JS file locally from the phone?

**EDIT:**

My phonegap application has a index.html file in the www directory that simply redirect to my server (ie. http://www.myserver.com). What I want to do is importing CSS or JS files in my server and take them directly from the phone.

Maybe can I use a iframe (in the index.html file) and load there all the code in my server instead of using a redirect?

Comment: Did you tried `fileSystem.root.fullPath` of css/js file ?

Comment: Have you tried `var importedDoc = link.import;` in `addEventListener` like as shown [here](http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-html-imports/)

Comment: Did you have use webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); for accessing file

Comment: @VanDir Simplest solution wil be to use this plugin - https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd which embeds a tiny server in the cordova application which allows local file access via HTTP protocols. Will create a working sample now if possible.

Comment: @VanDir The second approach you tried via. <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/www/css/file.css"> is not required i believe. You can refer it from project root path. Infact, if you create a sample cordova project using "cordova create HelloWorld", you can see how the index.css file inside www/css folder is referred in index.html

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I have edited the question with more details. @Gandhi I will see this plugin.

Comment: @VanDir After your update, i suggest you to check out this plugin - https://github.com/manifoldjs/ManifoldCordova Hope it helps

Comment: @VanDir Any update on this Vandir?

Answer (score 3):

In your second attempt, you placed the file in the css subfolder of the www root folder. That's the right way to do it, but then you need reference it using a relative path like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/file.css" />
```

**Edit**

First of all, if your app is redirecting to the server, Apple and maybe other stores will reject your app. According to [Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality), your app must have functionality beyond being just a "repackaged website".

Having said that, since you're redirecting to the server, so your CSS (and JS) is best left on the server and not imported locally. Just make sure your webpage works properly in browser and links to the CSS file on the server in the standard way, and it will work properly when your app redirects to it.

Of course, you need to whitelist your website, but I assume that you've already done that.

Comment: Thank you all for your answer but your solution doesn't work. I have edited the question with more details that implicitly explain why.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar when reading a file locally to include some content into the page.

You should be able to use this method and apped the CSS to a STYLE Tag on the page vs. using a LINK. You may have to tweak the path to get it right.

```
var filePath = "/android_asset/www/css/file.css";

$.get(filePath, function (data) {         
    $("#css-container").append(filePath);
});     

<style id="css-container"></style>
```